# How to send image to FTP Client in android?

Tags: android, url, upload, ftp, ftp-client

I am developing an android application in that i need to send my image to the Specific FTP URL address can any one help me how can I do that please.

URL is:
http://demo1.idevtechnolabs.com/RChatAPI/usrPhotos/

And My Code is:

```
public class ImageGallery extends Activity
{

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int PICK_Camera_IMAGE = 2;
    private ImageView imgView;
    private Button upload,cancel;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    Uri imageUri;
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    String filePath = null;
    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imguploadbtn);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imgcancelbtn);

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if (bitmap == null) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageGallery.this, "Uploading","Please wait...", true);
                    new ImageGalleryTask().execute();
                }
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageGallery.this.finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
                 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                 inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_image_gallery, menu);
                 return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case R.id.camera:
                String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image captured by camera");

                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_Camera_IMAGE);
                return true;

            case R.id.gallery:
                try 
                {
                        Intent gintent = new Intent();
                        gintent.setType("image/*");
                        gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gintent, "Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        switch (requestCode) 
        {
                case PICK_IMAGE:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                    {
                        selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    }
                    break;
                case PICK_Camera_IMAGE:
                     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
                     {
                        //use imageUri here to access the image
                        selectedImageUri = imageUri;
                        /*Bitmap mPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mPic, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())));*/
                    } 
                    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                     break;
            }

            if(selectedImageUri != null)
            {
                    try 
                    {
                        // OI FILE Manager
                        String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                        // MEDIA GALLERY
                        String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                        if (selectedImagePath != null) 
                        {
                            filePath = selectedImagePath;
                        }
                        else if (filemanagerstring != null) 
                        {
                            filePath = filemanagerstring;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                        }

                        if (filePath != null) 
                        {
                            decodeFile(filePath);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            bitmap = null;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
            }

    }

    class ImageGalleryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) 
        {
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try 
            {
                ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("My URL Address"));
                ftpClient.login("My Username", "My Password");
                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("My Path of URL");

                if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) 
                {
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
                    String path=selectedImageUri.toString();
                    Log.v("Image Path:",filePath);

                    buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                    ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream(buffIn, progressHandler);
                    boolean result=ftpClient.storeUniqueFile(progressInput);
                    boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(localAsset.getFileName(), progressInput);
                    buffIn.close();
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.d("Error in ftp:",e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) 
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) 
        {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } 
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void decodeFile(String filePath) 
    {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) 
        {
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

When I use this code and click on upload button
I got the following error:

```
Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient', referenced from method com.androidmyway.demo.imagedemo.ImageGallery$ImageGalleryTask.doInBackground
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simple example to upload any file over webserver from [here](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106).

Comment: I had tried this but I need to upload an image to FTP Client not on any URL. This example works when I send image to the URL address

Comment: Check this : http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120

FTP works on port number 21 for uploading so please try to provide 21 while connecting like `ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("My URL Address"),21);`

Comment: Is 21 is fixed on any port mam?

Comment: Same error :( I am trying this for 2 days but cant successed. Please help me even I coudnt find solution from any web-site. What is the permisson required for FTP?

Comment: Yes they are fixed in TCP and UDP protocols for detail refer here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Thanks for the valuable Information mam. But how can I solve this problem. :(

Comment: did you downloaded this external library and added in your project? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi

Comment: Is that any inbuilt library for upload an image?

Comment: Its library to access FTP related classes and method to do get server access.

Comment: Is there neccessary to Convert Picture to Bitmap while send it to server?

Comment: It's good practice to send data in byte array, It does not overhead the heap and buffer space.

Comment: hmmm but when i sent image to FTP server the File is currpted and become in .tmp format.

Comment: FTPClient class has "last packet data loss bug". so this was solved with 3.0.1 23.05.2011 release. Please download this  or above version of class.

Comment: My problem is that FTP couldnt Connect with The Client.?   ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("My URL Address"),21);

Comment: Just try this example http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120 it works for me

Comment: Hey m using your code is there need to any external library or Jar in the project?

Comment: hmm i had already added ftp4j-1.6.jar but it have an error, is there any other library need to be included?

Comment: download this and add to your project http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/download.php

Comment: Still Same. "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Comment: Thre arent run time error in androidexample code there are compile time error in library

Comment: Error is in those 2 lines. "import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferListener;" while i already added library ftp4j.

Comment: just keep sauronsoftware.ftp4j library it's getting conflicted

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dependency for using FTPClient class. You can find it easily on anywhere. it is "commons apache" named dependency.